# How to separate the query results on the same page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a page, which has two sections:
1) List of questions;
2) Top-voted list of questions

These two queries use the same call to the backend API, the only difference is I pass an additional parameter, e.g. showPopular=true in the latter case.

When I try to render data, whatever action retrieves last overwrites data in both sections. How do I distinguish such data?

I am using ReactJS, Redux.
This is to retrieve data:

```
query={showPopular:true}
this.props.actions.loadQuestions(accountId, query);
```

I have

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        error: state.questions.error,
        questions: state.questions.questions|| [],
        isLoading: state.questions.isLoading
    };
}
```

Comment: Any reducer action code? Are you using same action and reducer for this two queries?

Comment: Yes, all the code are the same. I can see on the backend, that the data is being returned correctly.

Comment: You have two options: make different actions and different reducers, or if you can get that boolean in the response, only make a condition in the reducer to check if you are getting all the questions or only the last voted, and store them in a different way to be able to get the whole set of questions or only the top voted questions

Comment: Don't want to follow the first option, this would make an unnecessary code for only one parameter.  I guess, the second option would mean to make changes to the reducer to change the state structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should at least separate state/prop/reducer because this two list are totally different, and they obviously will render different DOM.

The mapState should have different props mapping:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        error: state.questions.error,
        questions: state.questions.questions|| [],
        topQuestions: state.questions.topQuestions,
        isLoading: state.questions.isLoading
    };
}
```

You didn't post the reducer but it should also separate the two action or by using condition to update different state:

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_QUESTION:
      if(action.query.showPopular){
        return state.set('topQuestions', action.data);
      }else{
        return state.set('questions', action.data);
      }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```